# Submission canceled error when using form created in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I do not know a whole lot about javascript etc and I am trying to create some tabs that load a list of rows of dynamic data from mysql when the tab buttons are clicked. I have it set up so it loads fresh data each click. Anyway, after a lot of reading I was able to get everything working properly until I tried adding a button   to each row to remove the rows and also delete the record in mysql.
The problem is I can get the rows to delete visually but I get this error when the form tries calling the php script to remove the record:

```
Form submission canceled because the form is not connected
```

I am using ajax to call a php script that queries the database and builds the rows and adds the forms/buttons etc for loading into the tabs. It is basically something like this.

```
<?php
//get_data.php

if (isset($_POST['button'])){
$postval = $_POST['button'];
if ($postval == 'def_tab'){

//I run the mysql query here.

$cnt = 0;

// mysql array
foreach($row as $item){

//I build the elements etc here as well as data for the list

echo '<li class="list-items">
//Using this form as a removal button

<form name="rem" action="remove.php" method="post" data-target="rem' . $cnt . '" id="forms">
<input name="name" type="hidden" value="'.$item['value'].'">
<input type="submit"  class="remove" value=""></form>';
</li>
$cnt++
}

}
```

Here is some basic html where the contents from get_data.php are loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tab">
<button class="tabs" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab1')" id="def_tab">Tab 1</button>
<button class="tabs" onclick="openTab(event, 'tab2')" id="tab2">Tab 2</button>
</div>
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
<ul class="container"></ul></div>
</body>
```

Here is the jquery code that I am using.

```
<script>

// This removes the row properly but gives the form submission error

$('body').on('click', 'form[data-target]', function(event){
$(this).closest('.list-items').remove();
});
</script>

<script>
//Loads the default tab on page load, 
//calls the php script and adds the rows 
//from the ajax response to the container ul class.

$(document).ready(function() {
updatePage("def_tab");
$("#def_tab, #tab2").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var btnVal = this.id;
     updatePage(btnVal);
  });
 });
function updatePage(btnVal){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"get_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'button': btnVal},
        cache: false,
        async: true, 
        success:function(data){
        $('.container').html("");
        $(".container").append(data);
  }});
}
</script>

<script>
  //Some code for the tabs

  function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tabs;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
  for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

I think the problem is caused from loading the form in the ajax call dynamically and I am not sure what to do. I have been reading about appending the form to the body by using code such as this `$(document.body).append(form);` but I haven't been able to figure something out that works.
I didn't want this to be a mile long so I tried to post the most relevant parts so hopefully someone will understand what I am trying to do and how I can fix it. I'd just like to be able to remove the rows visually as well as run a simple deletion script to remove the row from the database as well. Thanks

Comment: you are removing the form from the dom and then it is trying to submit itself. Where is the code to delete the row from database? if you are expecting the form submission to cause the delete then you cannot remove it from the dom. You have to make a new ajax call where you pass just the id of the row/record you wish to delete and only then you should remove the row from the dom.

Comment: I was thinking I was going to have to do another ajax call I was just wondering if there was a way to avoid that. The deletion code is just an id sent via POST by the form to the php script where a simple query for the id is done and then deleted if found. It works fine, I just couldn't get past that form submission error.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve noticed that you´ve typed twice type:'post', the first in lowercases and the second time in uppercases type: "POST".

Comment: Yeah, I probably did that when I was trying to break the code apart to make it small enough to post on here without it being a mile long. My original code looks fine.

Comment: In php text, you close echo sentence, before you finalize the tag <li>. You type: </form>'; </li>. You have to put semicolon after </li>;

Comment: Yeah I just seen that but my original code is fine, I just threw all that code together real fast as an example but thanks for telling me anyway.